# body.scrollTop vs documentElement.scrollTop vs window.pageYOffset vs window.scrollY

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, scrolltop

When trying to find out how much a web page has been scrolled from the top, which of these should one use:

`document.body.scrollTop`,

`document.documentElement.scrollTop`,

`window.pageYOffset`,

`window.scrollY`

Which one(s) would I choose in these 2 separate scenarios:

a) If I wanted maximum compatibility (across the main browsers used currently)?

b) If I wanted code that was most standards compliant/future-proof/strict-mode-compatible (but didn't care about supporting old/non-standard browsers)?

Answer (score 38):

I'm using three of them in the skrollr source

```
return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop || 0;
```

https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/blob/b98d40820b9864be275e81af382045d72cc5a08a/src/skrollr.js#L627

a) So far it's working across all browsers (nobody complaint in the past year).

b) Since it will use the first one that is defined, I guess it's pretty future proof and stable.

If you're fancy you could do this as well

```
Math.max(window.pageYOffset, document.documentElement.scrollTop, document.body.scrollTop)
```

Comment: @Amio thanks, I updated the link to a specific commit so it won't change again

Comment: Better use `document.documentElement.scrollTop`

Comment: What browser is `window.pageYOffset` used for?

Comment: @Jessica I think Netscape (!).

Answer (score 5):

Given that skrollr does not use `window.scrollY`, this may have been obvious, but as further answer to the original question: `window.pageYOffset` is an alias for `window.scrollY`. See [Window.scrollY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY#Notes).

Answer (score 3):

To **Prinzhorn**'s answear:

Since `body` and `documentElement` is `undefined` in Chrome/Firefox, better use:

```
return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop || 0;
```

Tested myself.

Comment: document.body.scrollTop in FF doesn't work and document.documentElement.scrollTop behaves strange: values sometimes are odd.

Answer (score 3):

```
console.log('body.scrollTop : ' + document.body.scrollTop);
console.log('documentElement.scrollTop : ' + document.documentElement.scrollTop);
console.log('window.pageYOffset : ' + window.pageYOffset);
console.log('window.scrollY : ' + window.scrollY);
```

Output 1:

```
0

184.8000030517578

184.8000030517578

184.8000030517578
```

Output 2:

```
0

185.8000037517577

185.8000037517577

185.8000037517577
```

And so on...

**Tested on Google Chrome** - Version 85.0.4183.121 (Official Build) (64-bit)

```
document.body.scrollTop
```

It always gives 0 here but others three works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome uses `documentElement.scrollTop`, firefox uses `body.scrollTop`

Comment: this does not seem true for me. i can confirm what @iamfnizami said. `document.body.scrollTop === 0`  always, for chrome and firefox.