# How to Toggle Show/Hide a Fixed Element When Scrolling Through a Specific Div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, scroll

I am trying to figure out how to toggle between showing and hiding a fixed-positioned element when scrolling through a specific div.

Here is a diagram of what I would like to accomplish:

[image]

So far, I've been able to hide `#div2` when another div (`#div3`) is visible within a window, (as shown in the snippet provided), but I would like for it to be hidden as well before it reaches the scroll top position of `#div1`.

Alternatively, I suppose a more ideal solution would be to just assign the div to toggle display only within the top and bottom scroll point parameters of `#div1`.

Any suggestions?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $window = $(window);
  var div2 = $('#div2');
  var div1 = $('#div1');
  var div1_top = div1.offset().top;
  var div1_height = div1.height();
  var div1_bottom = div1_top + div1_height;
  console.log(div1_bottom);
  $window.on('scroll', function() {
    var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
    var viewport_height = $(window).height();
    var scrollTop_bottom = scrollTop + viewport_height;
    div2.toggleClass('hide', scrollTop_bottom > div1_bottom);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #ccffcc;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#div1 {
  background: #0099ff;
  height: 1500px;
  color: #fff;
}

#div2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #ffff00;
  color: #000;
}

#div2.hide {
  display: none;
}

#div3 {
  height: 100px;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
Scroll area <b>before</b> arriving to the top of <b>div1</b>
<br>
<i>(Scrolling through this area <u>should not</u> display <b>div2</b>)</i>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">This is <b>div2</b></div>
  This is <b>div1</b>
  <br>
  <i>(Toggle show/hide <b>div2</b> when scrolling past the top of this element)</i>
</div>
<div id="div3">
  This is <b>div3</b>
  <br>
  <i>(Toggle show/hide <b>div2</b> every time this div becomes visible in the window)</i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your `scroll` handler. You just need a second condition that adds the viewport height to the current `scrollTop` for the check at the bottom.

Also, it worked better to use [`document.documentElement.scrollTop`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618545/body-scrolltop-vs-documentelement-scrolltop-vs-window-pageyoffset-vs-window-scro?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) instead.

Finally, I changed your `.hide` to `.show` and started `#div2` out as `display: none`. Your toggle now uses this class.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $window = $(window);
  var div2 = $('#div2');
  var div1 = $('#div1');
  var div1_top = div1.offset().top;
  var div1_height = div1.height();
  var div1_bottom = div1_top + div1_height;
  console.log(div1_bottom);
  $window.on('scroll', function() {
    var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    var viewport_height = $window.height();
    var scrollTop_bottom = scrollTop + viewport_height;
    div2.toggleClass('show', scrollTop > div1_top && (scrollTop + window.innerHeight) < div1_bottom);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #ccffcc;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#div1 {
  background: #0099ff;
  height: 1500px;
  color: #fff;
}

#div2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #ffff00;
  color: #000;
display: none;
}

#div2.show {
  display: block;
}

#div3 {
  height: 100px;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
Scroll area <b>before</b> arriving to the top of <b>div1</b>
<br>
<i>(Scrolling through this area <u>should not</u> display <b>div2</b>)</i>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">This is <b>div2</b></div>
  This is <b>div1</b>
  <br>
  <i>(Toggle show/hide <b>div2</b> when scrolling past the top of this element)</i>
</div>
<div id="div3">
  This is <b>div3</b>
  <br>
  <i>(Toggle show/hide <b>div2</b> every time this div becomes visible in the window)</i>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. It is working as you mentioned; however, I would prefer for `#div2` to hide when the bottom of the browser window reaches the bottom of `#div1` instead of the `#div2` element itself. Would you know how to execute this?

Comment: @nrweb sorry about that, it should be better now

Comment: Great solution! Thanks for the additional input, just what I was looking for.